# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'googleUri' of null? Using Interface to 2 way binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to do 2way binding with my interface but kept getting 'set property of null'?

When i hit submit, which triggers the onSave function, I get the error "Cannot set property 'googleUri' of null?". The console log output as null. How do i fix this while using my interface?

This is my interface

```
export interface User {
    googleUri?: string;
}
```

this is my component HTML

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSave()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="googleUri">Google Excel Address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="googleUri" id="googleUri" [ngModel]="user?.googleUri" (ngModelChange)="user.googleUri=$event"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

my component TS

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  private user: User = {};
  public loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private onSave(): void {
    console.log(this.user);
    this.userService.saveUserSettings(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => this.loading = false
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For two way binding of data, you can directly use **[(ngModel)]**
You can replace your code with below code:

```
<input type="text" name="googleUri" id="googleUri" [(ngModel)]="user.googleUri"/>
```

I have created the same example as you mentioned above, and I am able
 to access the **googleUri** variable in the component.

Please verify with below thing:

> whether you have imported the User interface in the component
>   correctly or not ??

Please see the demo example here.
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-53019735)

Hope this will help you.
You can check the below result image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change private to 'public' for user object.

```
public user: User = {};
```

In Template, you can print the model object with pre.

```
<pre>
{{user | json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Yea, but i want to use interface. I will be using <pre>
{{user | async}}. 
</pre>